# Google sheet - retrieving the old Data validation instead of Data validation rules

Tags: google-sheets

`

```
function onEdit(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Gov")
  
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  
  if(activeCell.getColumn() >= 3 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
  
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

      var makes = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
      var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
      
        if(makeIndex != 0) {
  
      var validationRange = datass.getRange(2, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
  
  }
  
}
}
```

`

I was using this code to create independent dorp down list, but my data validation view was change to Data validation rules, how to get back to the original view.
Also every google sheet I opened showing the same Data validation rules

[[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Svh5.png)]
[[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RW1M.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in theory nothing should change. However, I will say as someone who's been making sheets projects for some time. I DO NOT LIKE THE UPDATE!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Google announced last week that they are replacing drop-down lists with [dropdown chips](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/12/drop-down-chips-google-sheets.html). The change includes a new look and the sidebar you show in the screenshot. Dropdown functionality remains the same, and the code you show will probably continue to work without changes.

There is no way to revert or downgrade back to the classic drop-down list view. All Google spreadsheets will use the new dropdown chips once the rollout is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Google's new data validation can be easily broken by pressing 'Delete' on the cell - the entire DV gets erased, not just the entry.